# useState acting out when trying to update with a setTimeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use setTimeout to flip a useState between true and false every 6 seconds. I use this state to add/ remove a class from a div - this will cause the div to toggle between `top: 0` to `top: 100%` (and a `transition` takes care of the animation).

To be more specific, I have an iPhone wrapper image with a content image inside it. The idea is that it will slowly scroll to the bottom of the content image, and then after 6 seconds (from the time it started scrolling down), it will then start scrolling back up, ad infinitum. However, it's not working right at all.

I've tested it with an onClick and it works exactly as I intend. However, with the setTimeout logic:

- The state is *always* false - even if we set it to true and then log it
- The state is always *true* from the perspective of the JSX - the class is always added, which implies that the state is true

Of course, it cannot be true and false, and it should be flipping its value. Could someone tell me why it's not working and perhaps tell me why it's acting in this bizarre way?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import iphone from '../Images/iphone.png'

const Iphone = (props) => {
    const [isInitialised, setInitialised] = useState(false)
    const [animating, setAnimating] = useState(false)

    const startAnimation = () => {
        setAnimating(!animating); /* Even if I use `true`, it will log to the console as `false` */
        console.warn('animation change iphone!');
        console.warn(animating);
        console.warn(isInitialised); /* This also always logs as `false` */

        setTimeout(() => {
            startAnimation();
        }, 6000);
    }

    if (!isInitialised) {
        setInitialised(true);
        startAnimation();
    }

    return (
        <div className={`iphone align-mobile-center ${animating ? "iphone--animating" : ""}`} onClick={() => setAnimating(!animating)}>
            <img className="iphone__image" src={iphone} alt="An iPhone" />
            <div className="iphone__content">
                <img className="iphone__content-image" src={props.image} alt={props.alt} />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Iphone;
```

I use the `isInitialised` otherwise it seems to hit an infinite loop.

Comment: bing setTimeout to outside and setState inside setTimeout function

Comment: Remember to clear the timeout, otherwise it will be recreated on every render. Perhaps put it inside a `useEffect`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this.
useEffect with empty array as deps so it will only once, you don't need isInitialized state.

In useEffect use setInterval so it will run every 6 seconds.

use callback way to setting state so you always get the correct value of animating.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import iphone from '../Images/iphone.png'

const Iphone = (props) => {
    const [animating, setAnimating] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
      const startAnimation = () => {
        setAnimating(v => !v);
      }
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        startAnimation();
      }, 6000);
      return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className={`iphone align-mobile-center ${animating ? "iphone--animating" : ""}`} onClick={() => setAnimating(!animating)}>
            <img className="iphone__image" src={iphone} alt="An iPhone" />
            <div className="iphone__content">
                <img className="iphone__content-image" src={props.image} alt={props.alt} />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Iphone;
```

Comment: Just a side note, but you should probably assign the interval to some variable and then clear the interval in the returned function from `useEffect` when the component unmounts

Comment: @Simon good catch. Updated answer with clear interval.

Answer (score 1):

you can use useEffect and bring setTimeout outside.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import iphone from '../Images/iphone.png'

const Iphone = (props) => {
    const [isInitialised, setInitialised] = useState(false)
    const [animating, setAnimating] = useState(false)
    useEffect(()=>{
       startAnimation();
    },[]);
    const startAnimation = () => {
        setAnimating(!animating); 
        console.warn('animation change iphone!');
        console.warn(animating);
        console.warn(isInitialised);
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
      if (!isInitialised) {
        setInitialised(true);
        startAnimation();
      }
    }, 6000);



    return (
        <div className={`iphone align-mobile-center ${animating ? "iphone--animating" : ""}`} onClick={() => setAnimating(!animating)}>
            <img className="iphone__image" src={iphone} alt="An iPhone" />
            <div className="iphone__content">
                <img className="iphone__content-image" src={props.image} alt={props.alt} />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Iphone;
```

Comment: This works if I nudge the `startAnimation` out of the `isInitialised` check, many thanks. Worryingly, if I save it in VSCode, ESLint adds `startAnimation` to the array at the end of the `useEffect` which causes it to rapidly call it over and over. I'm not sure why or how to get around this without disabling the extension...

Comment: @DevMan that eslint rules for hooks which requires you to add values inside effect as dependency.  can you check my answer and see if it works for you

Comment: @AmitChauhan I updated the `useEffect` to `useCallback` and it's now working fine with the `[startAnimation]` bit at the end

Comment: @AmitChauhan I updated the code with your answer - needed to add a `startAnimating` to the useEffect to get it to run immediately (in addition to running every 6 seconds) but it works and removes the need for the initialised state. Many thanks